# What's the best way for UX/UI designers to hand-off assets to developers working in QML?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, user-experience, qt3d

I'm a UX designer working with a team on new 3D software, we are all new to QML. My current tools (Sketch, Zeplin, Invision, Abstract) don't export design assets to QML code, like they do for CSS. What's the best way for a designer to hand-off design assets for implementation in QML?

I've looked into the documentation for Qt Creator and found the processes they suggest don't work or is cumbersome (they recommend using a third-party plug-in for Photoshop or Gimp). Designing directly in Qt is inefficient, as we need to iterate rapidly. I've also tried one plugin I found for Sketch, but am getting errors (SketchQML).

Would be great to be able to hand-off design assets that can be inspected in QML format for development.

Comment: What about Qt Designer tool for QML ? https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-using-qt-quick-designer.html

Comment: Yeah ... as a result we have then 200M code of just a calculator. What about scripts, application logic etc.? You cannot avoid coding anyway ...